# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, syntax-error

I checked everything. It still isn’t working and when I put semicolon ( ; ) in line 6 it says

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in line 6
```

What should I do? Here is my code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['logintoadminpanel']))
(   

    include_once 'connection.php';

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    if(empty($username) || empty($password))
    (
        echo "Please fill the required fields";
    )
)
?>
```

Comment: this is a syntax error.. check your file might be you are missing semicolon (;)

Answer (score 4):

You're using parens for blocks. You need to use braces.

```
if (...)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use { } instead of ( ) for if condition.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['logintoadminpanel']))
{

    include_once 'connection.php';

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    if(empty($username) || empty($password))
    {
        echo "Please fill the required fields";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check below tested code.. 

<?php

if(isset($_POST['logintoadminpanel']))
{

    include_once ('connection.php');

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


    if(empty($username) || empty($password))
    {
        echo "Please fill the required fields";
    }
}
?>
```